# IIS site binds only a specific IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

Somehow IIS resists to bind any/exist/new site on another IP. To test I did bind POP3 service on other IP:port80 and telnet successfully.

HTTP service won't start on other IP:port

What's wrong with IIS?

**UPDATE:** More info for non-skilled people:

Network adapter has many IP addresses like below:
x.y.z.42 (primary)
x.y.z.43
x.y.z.44
x.y.z.45

I can ping all of them. 43 is the default IP for web service. I can telnet x.y.z.43 80 with no problem.

I've added a test site runs on IP x.y.z.43, I can navigate it, telnet it. Everything is ok.

I've also added another binding that test site: x.y.z.44, however I cannot navigate site at http://x.y.z.44, or cannot telnet.

netstat displays only x.y.z.43:80 as listening. So there is no service binding on IP x.y.z.44.

I've removed the ip 44, configured POP3 service to run on ip x.y.z.44 port 80. I could telnet port 80. So there was nothing on port 80, it was unused.

It's Windows Server 2008 Standard. I'm not working from a remote pc, so firewall or internet connection & remote access won't block me. I can start a service on ip x.y.z:44 port:80 and make a connection. In short; IIS resists to start on another IP except x.y.z.43.

I've examined Event Log but no luck. I think I have to take a look to text logs of IIS, etc.

Comment: More information is needed on your setup.  There's not much to go on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix:

> netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=x.y.z.44

[Link: Netsh commands for HTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this article? I used it when I was having issues with iis
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734869.aspx

Comment: It would help to post some relevant information from the link.  Links break over time.  If that happens your answer will essentially be lost.